# How to validate these elements in PHP?

Tags: php

I have checkboxes with the following names:

**chk-cloud-a** 
**chk-cloud-b** 
and so on...

**chk-dco-a** 
**chk-dco-b** 
and so on...

How do I validate after form submission such that: 
Atleast one element from the checkboxes with name starting with **chk-cloud** or **chk-dco** must be ticked?

I hope someone can help me with this.

Cheers!

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["chk-cloud"]))` and so on !!

Comment: I have at least 9 elements per group. Using manual if-else will ruin the code readibility.

Comment: Is it possible to use a group? `<input type="checkbox" name="chk-dco[a]"> <input type="checkbox" name="chk-dco[b]">` + `count($_POST['chk-dco'])` ?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're checkboxes then all you really care about is whether or not they have a value.  What that value is is not significant.

All you need to do is check that there are elements in the $_GET or $_POST (depending on form submission method) that contain fields of that name.

```
if (array_key_exists ('chk-cloud-a ', $_POST)) {
    // Do what should happen of that checkbox is checked
}
```

If the problem is that you have multiple similar checkboxes then you might want to consider grouping them together in an array.  This is done by using square bracket notation in the field name:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk-cloud[a]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk-cloud[b]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk-cloud[c]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk-cloud[d]" />
```

You can use a loop to process such a group

```
foreach ($_POST [chk-cloud] as $key => $value) { // We're really only interested in the key
    handleCheckbox ($key) // handleCheckbox is some function you've wrote
}
```

Or

```
foreach (array_keys ($_POST [chk-cloud]) as $key) { // Logically the same as above
```

Comment: true, but one can also just alter the value of checkboxes as well.

Comment: I'll try this one. Seems like a good idea to me. However, I have chk-cloud-a up to chk-cloud-i, is there any easier way to know if there's a checkbox ticked from the group, something like regex?

Comment: @kennypu That can be problematic if the values happen to be something that evaluates to false.  The array_key_exists method always works if the checkbox was checked, regardless of what its value actually was.  It's important to never trust external input in PHP because you don't know where that input came from.  It could be a doctored version of your page that submits pathological values, or even an automated script that makes repeated curl requests in an attempt to hack your site.  The more you depend on external values being right the more at risk you are.

Comment: Can these checkbox groups you're talking about be ticked like normal checkboxes? Like 2 checkboxes ticked for index 'a' and so on?

Comment: @JellyAce Yes.  If any of the checkboxes are checked you'll get an array called chk-cloud in the response, and each element in that array will be whatever is in the square brackets for the checked checkboxes.  If someone checks a and c you'll get `Array ([chk-cloud] => Array ([0] => a, [1] => c)` back

Answer (score 0):

Just use preg_match or strpos to check if any key in POST matches Your requirements. Personally i would make subarray of these elements and just check if its empty.

Comment: Just a little lame way but it will suit Your needs:
<?php
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
 if(strpos('chck-dco', $k) !== false) {
   return true
 }
}
}

Comment: I have an inkling that preg_match might help me with this, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Care to update your answer with that code you just answered? I'm pretty sure some people might find it helpful as well in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
function checkBoxValidate(){ //method to test checkbox
$array = array('a','b','c','d', ....); // make array for each checkbox name
foreach ($array as $a){
    if((isset($_REQUEST['chk-cloud-'.$a]) || isset($_REQUEST['hk-dco-'.$a])) &&  ($_REQUEST['chk-cloud-'.$a] == 'check_value' || $_REQUEST['hk-dco-'.$a] == 'check_value' ) ){
     return true;
    }
}
return false; //return no check box was checked
}
```